# Why can't I update TextView and ImageView from OnPostExecute (AsyncTask)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have code in which I want to update the textview and imageview of the InfoWindow. The image and text are retrieved from a sqlite database so I put this in an AsyncTask. When I want to update the textview and imageview of the InfoWindow from OnPostExecute, this doesn't work, the infowindow remains empty. 
I found similar questions on StackOverflow but none of the answers solved my problem.

This is my code:

```
   googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                        LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                        // find location id in database
                        Location location = dbhandler.getLocationByLatLng(latLng);
                        final int id = location.getId();
                        addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // open load image fragment
                                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                                LoadImageFragment fragment = new LoadImageFragment();
                                // pass id to new fragment
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putInt("id", id);
                                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            }
                        });
                        removeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // remove markers and images
                            }
                        });
                        new AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Location>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Location doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
                                LatLng latLng = params[0];
                                Location location = dbhandler.getLocationByLatLng(latLng);
                                return location;
                            }
                            // find image and text associated with Location
                            protected void onPostExecute(Location location) {
                                new AsyncTask<Location, Void, Image>() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected Image doInBackground(Location... params) {
                                        Location location = params[0];
                                        try {
                                            image = dbhandler.getImageByLocationId(location.getId());
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex){
                                            Log.d("debug", "failed to fetch image");
                                            image = null;
                                        }
                                        return image;
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onPostExecute(Image image) {
                                        // set image and description
                                        if(image != null) {
                                            infoImageView.setImageBitmap(image.getBitmap());
                                            infoTextView.setText(image.getDescription());

                                            updateInfoWindow(image);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }.execute(location);
                            }
                        }.execute(marker.getPosition());
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                // find Location in database

                // Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map
                googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
                    // Use default InfoWindow frame
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                        // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                        // Getting the position from the marker
                        final LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

                        infoImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.infoImage);
                        infoTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.infoText);
                        if(image != null) {
                            infoImageView.setImageBitmap(image.getBitmap());
                            infoTextView.setText(image.getDescription());
                        }

                        return v;
                    }

                });


            }
        });
```

Comment: can you post your log here

Comment: It doesn't give any errors, as far as I can see, just emulator errors but nothing regarding the code

Comment: may be some network error

Comment: Have you tested to debug it? is the execution is called?

Comment: Yes, just the TextView and Imageview can't be updated, but are called. Has this something to do with AsyncTask being a class within the class perhaps? OnPostExecute is on the main thread so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: any solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The **Info Windows** documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows) includes this note:

> **Note**: The info window that is drawn is *not* a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`. Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

So you have to hold a reference to the `Marker` whose info you're trying to show, download the image, set the image to your `ImageView`,and then re-call `marker.showInfoWindow()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sounds logical to me. How do I combine this with setInfoWindowAdapter?

Comment: Without having your whole codebase to play with, I can't say for sure. But I believe it should be as simple as adding `arg0.showInfoWindow()` to the end of your `onPostExecute()` implementations. When I've had to do this myself I've created a custom subclass of `InfoWindowAdapter`, which let me do things like declare private fields etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding arg0.showInfoWindow() at the end of onPostExecute() (this needed the marker to be declared final) but this didn't work. I updated the code in my original post to include more of the surrounding code.

Comment: Oh, of course. The problem is that `showInfoWindow()` will cause `getInfoContents()` to be executed for that marker, and your code has no way of knowing that your `AsyncTask` downloaded the image already. You'll have to create a custom subclass and store state about the marker and the downloaded image, etc. In my experience, I created one that held onto a `View` for my info window and always returned that exact view every time in `getInfoContents()`, so I was able to show a placeholder when the image wasn't already fetched and fill in the real image when it had been.

Answer (score 0):

please declare your variable Globally

```
Image image;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't help solve the problem unfortunately